# Unable to find bundled Java version. Android Studio,

Tags: flutter

Unable to find bundled Java version in flutter new version of Android Studio(Electric Eel) in Windows.
Android Studio Electric Eel Unable to find bundled Java version.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:-

1. Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr and copy the content
2. Copy the content and paste it to the C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre